# how to import json file into index.html (putting markers to maps)

Tags: javascript, html, json

I used scrapy to get all items data from a website
and then used geocode api to map address to lat,lon coordinates.

I wish to use those coordinates to put markers on a map.
I've seen examples where they put a few markers via brute force

i.e. var data = [[lat1, lon1 ],[lat2, lon2 ],[lat3, lon3 ]]

but my json file has more than 10,000 datas!

If I can import data to this html file just like python, it would be a life saver.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: Put `const data = [...];` in a file called `data.js` and include it like any other <script> above your actual script. Now use `data` in your main script. The alternative is to use fetch() to load the JSON file.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I wish to use fetch option do I need to upload my json file somewhere online?

Comment: Not necessarily; if you have a server, then you can just put it in the same folder. Note that if you don't have a server, (i.e. double-click an HTML file to open it in the browser and it says `file:///` in your address bar) you will suffer from all kinds of complications throughout your project. Use at least some basic local server solution like Apache.